# Настройка шрифта Unica One

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

Верстаю макет, в котором используется Unica One https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Unica+One, у него есть настройка regular, но phpstorm отказывается принимать такую запись:

```
font-family: "UnicaOne", regular;
```

Принимает запись `font-family: "UnicaOne", sans-serif;` но при такой записи шрифт выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если присмотреться это не тот шрифт. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Regular — это обычное начертание, в CSS такого значения у свойства `font` нет.
Не так вы вызываете использование этого шрифта, надо писать через пробел — `Unica One`.

```css
p {
  font-family: "Unica One", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One" rel="stylesheet">

<p>This is hand-typed text.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню к ответу Sasha Omelchenko немножко информации которая облегчит вам жизнь при работе с кастомными шрифтами:

**A).**  Присматриваться необязательно. Есть инструменты для отладки.
Например в chrome dev tools (F12 в хроме):
*1).* Инспектим элемент (Ctrl+Shift+C или соответствующая кнопка).
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*2).* Смотрим его computed styles
*3).* Листаем в самый низ и видим какой шрифт браузер отрендерил по факту и где его взял. И не надо замеров "на глаз".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**B).** Сначала следует подключить гуглофонт по быстрому "копипастом", а потом уже экспериментировать.
Для этого в гуглофонтах справа сверху плюсик "select this font".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Справа снизу появится выпадашка,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
надо на нее кликнуть, там будут адрес подключения и дефолтный стиль, можно сделать ctrl+c/ctrl+v и не делать ошибок в названии шрифтов или адресе подключения шрифта.

Comment: На примере этого ответа Вы можете видеть мой прогресс в рисовании стрелок